# What is this pointer and memory code printing? I don't know if it's printing garbage or how to print the value that I need

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

This is a snippet of code that I took from a bigger one. I need to figure out whether or not what I'm printing is garbage and how to change it for it to print the value I need.
I need it to print the value of `int id` instead of whatever it's printing. The output was `10813776` in this run and it, of course, changes whenever I change some code or relaunch DevC++.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> //Memory allocation (malloc)

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int id = 0;
    int nMemory = 0;
    int * pMemory;
    pMemory = (int *) malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    
    while(id < 20){
        if (pMemory != NULL){
            cout << "Numbers in memory: " << endl;
            pMemory = new int[id];
            nMemory = *pMemory;
            cout << nMemory << endl;
        }
        id++;
    }
    delete pMemory;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to C++. I know that I'll only need 20 integers, so that's why I used it. Any advantage to using ```new```? How would I implement it?

Comment: *I'm fairly new to C++* -- If this is the case, where did you get the idea to use `malloc` in a C++ program?  No C++ book I know of shows this.  It is undefined behavior to allocate memory using `malloc`, and deallocate it using `delete`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I read 'A Tour of C++' second edition by Bjarne Stroustrup, which was recommended by Derek Banas, whose [tutorial](https://youtu.be/6y0bp-mnYU0?t=6150) I'm following. He used malloc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just need a simple code that allocates 20 blocks of memory (```int``` sized), writes a value to it, and then prints the values stored in those blocks. I am aware it is overall messy, although unaware of its bad behaviors and why. I'd rewrite it completely, were I knowledgeable enough to do it.
I understood what he was doing, but I need something that goes a step further. Clearly, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Tour's good, but it's best used as a refresher. The preference order when allocating storage should go Automatic, [library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), `new`, `malloc`. About the only time you should pull out `malloc` is really low-level scaffolding.

Comment: @DanielPantigoso It is not at all clear what this code is trying to accomplish. This code is just a jumble of messiness and bad behaviors. It needs to be completely rewritten. Whatever you took away from that tutorial is not what it was trying to teach you.

Comment: @DanielPantigoso -- If memory is allocated using `malloc` it is deallocated using `free`.  If memory is allocated with `new`, it is deallocated with `delete`.  If memory is allocated with `new[]`, it is deallocated with `delete[]`.  If you mix these pairs up, you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Think of `malloc` and `new` in a single C++ source as peanut-butter and barbecue sauce. Don't mix them -- they don't go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> pMemory = new int[id];
> nMemory = *pMemory;
> ```

The first line replaces the array you've `malloc`-ed with a new uninitialized one, and then tries to read from the first slot of that new array. You shouldn't be assigning directly to `pMemory`; maybe to `pMemory[someIndex]`, but not to `pMemory` itself.

Are you trying to read from the `pMemory` array and assign it to `nMemory`? If so, change the lines above to this:

```
nMemory = pMemory[id];
```

Your entire loop should look more like this:

```
if (pMemory != NULL) {
    cout << "Numbers in memory: " << endl;
    while(id < 20) {
        nMemory = pMemory[id];
        cout << nMemory << endl;
        id++;
    }
}
```

Or, with a more idiomatic `for` loop:

```
if (pMemory != NULL) {
    cout << "Numbers in memory: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << pMemory[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

(You're also going to have to initialize the array somewhere above this loop. I presume you do that in your real code, but if not: the code you posted allocates an array with `malloc()` but does not set the items to useful values. Make sure to set them to something meaningful before you then try to read and print them.)

Comment: My code used ints from a text file and wrote them to the memory, but it still prints out garbage. In all honesty, I don't know where exactly it's going wrong.

Comment: @DanielPantigoso nothing in the code you showed is filling the allocated memory with any data at all, let alone from a file. Please update your question to show a [mcve] demonstrating your real code.

Answer (score 2):

This code is leaking the memory blocks you allocate with `malloc()` and `new[]`.

You `malloc()` a block of memory and assign its address to `pMemory`, then you change `pMemory` to point at different memory addresses that are allocated with `new[]`. So you lose the ability to `free()` the `malloc()`'ed memory (you are not even trying to call `free()`).

And, this code is not freeing the memory allocated with `new[]` correctly. Memory allocated with `new[]` must be freed with `delete[]`, not with `delete`. Worse, you are calling `new[]` 20 times in a loop, but calling `delete` only once after the loop. So, you are leaking 19 blocks of `new[]`ed memory, and have *undefined behavior* freeing 1 block.

Now, to answer your actual question, the code is printing out garbage because the memory you are allocating with `new[]` is *uninitialized*, so the data you are trying to print from that memory contains *indeterminate* values.

Comment: I just read this after years of not touching C++ and this is such a great breakdown. Thank you!